# Finding an HTTP bottleneck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, nginx, linode

I'm developing a custom Blog application in Ruby on Rails, having load speed as a primary measure of success.

I'm caching (with Redis) both views and models to shorten up queries and rendering of raw HTML. Finally I succeeded loading a single post in under 15ms. Time to deploy.

I bought a Linode 20$/month machine with 2gb ram, 2 cores, ssd storage, 40gbit in, 250mbit out. The machine is hosted in London. I installed Ubuntu 15.04.

I set up Cloudflare free plan for more aggressive caching and minification of assets. I enabled the Full SSL functionality.

I installed nginx as a proxy to the Rails application running on Unicorn. Rails, Redis, PostgreSQL and nginx run on the same server.

I am in Rome, Italy. The nearest Cloudflare datacenter is in Milan, while the origin Linode server is in London. The average request time (as reported by the chrome network panel) is 230ms. Whops...

So first of all I checked out the Rails logs, and the log reported times (and the X-Runtime header) where consistent with my development data (< 20ms).

I edited nginx configuration to add an X-Time header:

```
add_header X-Time $request_time;
```

And that shows just a few ms over the Rails timings.

Then I enabled direct access to the server (disabled Cloudflare) and disabled SSL to remove the handshake overhead.

So I finally found that with or without Cloudflare, with or without SSL, load times where always quite random in the range [180-350]ms, with no apparent explaination.

Here's a shot of the Chrome timing panel, without both Cloudflare and SSL. Just a raw HTTP connection directly on port 80 of the nginx server.

[image: Chrome timing panel]

Why am I seeing such high times on a blazing fast application? What should I check next? Is the Linode server my bottleneck?

Thanks

### Edit

It looks like gzip compression as enabled by default by nginx was slowing the whole thing down by a 30%. I have now disabled it since Cloudflare will gzip it anyway in a second step. Now request times are between 120 and 200ms but I still feel like it could be improved.

Comment: Do you have gzip compression on or off in nginx?

Comment: [This](https://blog.cloudflare.com/ttfb-time-to-first-byte-considered-meaningles/) could be helpful.

Comment: Try to find how much time is spent by the DNS query (You may find that this takes more than you expect). In order to find the time `# dig -x yourdomain.com` and search the output for something like 'Query time: x msec'. I hope you have access to a Linux machine so you can run dig.

Comment: @chad_ It was on. As I disabled it timing went down in the [120-200]ms range. A nice 30% improvement. I think I can leave it disabled as Cloudflare will compress it later. I believe timings are still quite high though. Is there anything that can be done to improve?

Comment: @cristian It looks like DNS is slower than I thought (80ms to 300ms in a few subsequent queries). However I guess that chrome will cache the result after the first query so I'm not concerned about it.

Comment: @D-side Actually I'm quite concerned about TTFB since it's considered as a mayor ranking factor for SEO.

Comment: What are the ping times, ie what is pure network latency? Is the server doing reverse ip lookup for log files, it is quicker to defer that if possible.

Comment: How long response just to static file served?

Comment: Basic ping from home is 70ms-110ms. So I should assume that network congestion is my main bottleneck. Damn speed of light...

Comment: I'm glad that did it for you a little bit anyway.  I've seen similar issues on high performance apps.  I suspect in a more sluggish app this is true as well but it's not until you've stripped most things away that you're even aware of the 100-200ms.